# Using .htaccess to navigate to parent directory of last directory in URL

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, html5-history

I'm trying to write .htaccess code that will ignore the final subdirectory of a URL, route to the directory before that final subdirectory, but leave the URL intact.

This is in the context of an SPA in which I use JavaScript for routing.

If I navigate to directory xxx, which could be nested arbitrarily deeply:

```
https://my-site/[subdirectories]/xxx
```

...then when clicking on relative links within the xxx directory, such as to:

```
./aaa
./bbb
./ccc
```

...which would correspond to (and produce URLs of):

```
https://my-site/[subdirectories]/xxx/aaa
https://my-site/[subdirectories]/xxx/bbb
https://my-site/[subdirectories]/xxx/ccc
```

...then the JavaScript will detect the change in the URL and bring up the content for the "virtual" subdirectories `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`. Fine and dandy.

However, if I go to any of those URLs directly, i.e., by entering the URL directly, rather than using navigation within the site, then my site throws a 404 error, as the `aaa`, `bbb`, and `ccc` are not actual subdirectories. They are "virtual" subdirectories, not corresponding to actual folders on the server, and thus the error is thrown.

I want to write an .htaccess routine that will detect an initial navigation (direct opening of):

```
https://my-site/[subdirectories]/xxx/aaa
https://my-site/[subdirectories]/xxx/bbb
https://my-site/[subdirectories]/xxx/ccc
```

etc.

...and simply open this location:

```
https://my-site/[subdirectories]/xxx
```

...but preserve the "virtual" subdirectory on the end (`aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`) in the URL as displayed in the URL bar. My JavaScript will take over from there to bring in the desired content for `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`. (And this works fine after first navigating to `https://my-site/[subdirectories]/xxx` directly and then simply clicking on links to `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`; it's going to any of those "subdirectories" directly that's the problem.)

Can this be done with .htaccess? I'm struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to craft a rewrite rule that specifies a file for the destination content.

If the subdirectory names are known, and for this example they are `aaa`, `bbb`, and `ccc`, then the following rule opens the index.html file in the subdirectory while leaving the URL intact:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If it's not an actual directory...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# If it's not an actual file...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Provided aaa, bbb, and ccc are the known subdirectories,
# and (.+) represents ANY text that follows (i.e., any deeper
# subdirectory structure), then $1/index.html will route to
# the index.html file in whichever folder of the aaa|bbb|ccc list
# that is provided: 
RewriteRule ^(aaa|bbb|ccc)/(.+)$ $1/index.html [L]
```